# Alamofire request with cookies

Tags: swift, cookies, request, alamofire

I'm beginner and I can't figure out how to make a .GET request (however it requires autenthication) with Alamofire. I managed to do this with other web service (login) because it takes parameters argument:

```
parameters = [
 "username" : username
"password" : password 
]
```

Then:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, loginUrl, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

     //handling the response       
}
```

In response header I get some information:

```
[Transfer-Encoding: Identity, Server: nginx/1.4.1, Content-Type: application/json, P3P: policyref="http://www.somewebpage.com", CP="NON DSP COR CURa TIA", Connection: keep-alive, Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2015 13:49:20 GMT, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Set-Cookie: sessionid=5xeff47e65f674a4cc5b2d54f344304b; Domain=.somedomain.com; Path=/, tbauth=1; Domain=.somedomain.com; Path=/, Content-Encoding: gzip]
```

It's of type `[NSObject : AnyObject]`

What should I do with that information to store it in NSURLDefaults and prepare valid request parameter (cookie)? Do I need all fields or just Set-Cookie?

I tried manually set parameter:

```
parameters = [
 "Cookie" : "sessionid=5xeff47e65f674a4cc5b2d54f344304b; Domain=.somedomain.com; Path=/, tbauth=1; Domain=.somedomain.com; Path=/"
]
```

but it does return error NSURLErrorDomain -1017 (NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse)

Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 19):

Ok, after 2 weeks I just found a solution:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: query)!
let mutableUrlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableUrlRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let cookie = prefs.valueForKey("COOKIE") as String

mutableUrlRequest.setValue(cookie, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

Alamofire.request(mutableUrlRequest).responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

     //handling the response       
}
```

Comment: Nice one :) I tried with `forKey` and got errors all the time

Comment: How could you convert [String:String] into String?

Comment: Why did it take two weeks to find the solution?